# Send errors to another log - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, error-log

I wanted to know if I can send all the errors that happend while my app is in 'production' environment to a new 'log' instead of sending ALL the actions to the 'production.log' send it to 'production_errors.log'.

And if it is possible, tell me how please !

Thank you very much for reading !

Comment: Check the documentation? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

Comment: Yeap, I've checked it. 
But I don't really understand how to only write the erros on a new log while having a normal log too.

Comment: Write own logger maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In `config/environments/production.rb`, within the configuration block:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join(%w(log production_errors.log)), :error)
```

Comment: Error message:
can't convert Array into String

Exception class:
TypeError